# How to define its type when instantiate ``` typedef Widget SuccessCallback<T>(T data);```

Tags: flutter

`typedef Widget SuccessCallback<T>(T data);`

I want to define its type when instantiate above Class.

For example, When we pass it to another function, we normally pass something like `(data){ return widget}`; but at that time, data is `dynamic` type. I want to define it to a certain type.

How could i do this?

Comment: Can you maybe post complete code of what you *want* to do and where? I have a hard time understanding what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(data){ return widget; }
```

In this case, `data` is considered to be of type `dynamic` because you did not give it a type, it could not be inferred, and `dynamic` is the default.

```
(int data){ return widget; }
```

Now it has a type.